# random variable: loaded die

Tags: probability, random

We have two dice, one of which is loaded with faces numbered $\{1,1,2,3,4,5\}$. If we choose one of them and we launch it 5 times, let $X$ be the random variable "the number of times we get 1", calculates $P\{X>=2\}$ and $E[X]$?
We have two cases, when we choose a normal die:
$P\{X>=2\}=1-P\{X=0\}-P\{X=1\}=\frac{1526}{6^5}$,
when we choose a loaded die:
$P\{X>=2\}=1-P\{X=0\}-P\{X=1\}=\frac{131}{3^5}$,
I have used the binomial random variable with parameters respectively of:
$(n=5, p=\frac{1}{6})$ and $(n=5, p=\frac{2}{6})$.
Now i think that i should join this two cases but i don't know how to do it and if it is correct.

Using the inclusion exlusion principle:
$P\{X>=2\}=P\{X>=2\}_{N}+P\{X>=2\}_{L}-P(\{X>=2\}_{N}\{X>=2\}_{L})$,
where $L <=> \space loaded$, $N <=> normal$.

Comment: How to join it depends on how we choose the die.  Are the two dice equally likely to be chosen?

Comment: The problem doesn't not say that they are equally likely, but if it is true, i think we should use the inclusion-exlusion principle.

Comment: are you sure there are two faces with 1?

Comment: yes, the problem says there are two 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event of choosing the regular die.  Let $B$ be the event of choosing the loaded die.  Let $C$ be the event of rolling a $1$.  $Pr(C)=Pr(C\cap A)+Pr(C\cap B)$, because $A,B$ are complementary events.  You have calculated $Pr(C|A)$ and $Pr(C|B)$ already. Combining, $Pr(C)=Pr(C|A)Pr(A)+Pr(C|B)Pr(B)$.